# Difference between Jupyter Server and Python interpreter in DataSpell

Tags: jupyter, dataspell

I work with Jupyter notebooks in Jetbrain's DataSpell. In two places I can configure a python interpreter. What is the difference between

1. Python Interpreter (lower right, in my case Conda env "mpd")
2. Jupyter-Server/ Managed Server (upper right, in my case WSL)

I think this should be the same, not?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the lower right corner, you see the default Python interpreter configured in your system to run your python scrips. E.g. you have a *.py file in your DataSpell workspace.

The one shown under the Jupyter configuration is the one which will be used for running your notebooks.

If you run Jupyter locally and have just one interpreter, it will be the same for both. However, you can have multiple Python environments in your system and use one for Jupyter and another for your local scripts.

Comment: This is such an unnecessary layer of complexity.